# Gingerbread default web browser multiple click issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, backbone.js, browser, android-2.3-gingerbread

This is an obscure issue and I'm posting it just in case someone else runs into it.

I am developing Node/Backbone/Marionette JavaScript web application that uses snap.js to hide / show a navigation drawer. At the top of the page there is a hamburger button (opens / closes the snap drawer) and two primary action buttons horizontally aligned.

On Android Gingerbread (2.3.X) the default browser responds to touches by firing TWO click events. This is problematic because the hamburger button slides away during the first click event and the second (same screen location as the first) fires on one of the action buttons.

This has been a nightmare to debug and I almost resolved it by changing the horizontal layout.

Answer (score 0):

On a random chance, I decided to install fastclick.js (https://github.com/ftlabs/fastclick) cuz it's awesome anyway and it resolved my double click issue!! I believe it does because there is no longer a ~300ms delay between each click event. Regardless, I hope you will be as joyous as I was when this evil bug died!